# How to fetch form parameters while using multipart/form-data in Spring?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to fetch a file using *html* form. When I use `enctype=multipart/form-data`, I am unable to fetch form parameters and file upload.

Do I need to do any special configuration while using `enctype=multipart/form-data` in *Spring*?

**JSP code:**

```
<form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/bucket">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
      <input type = "submit"  value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/bucket")

    public ModelAndView exec(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

           String fileString = request.getParameter("file");//this is NULL.

    }
```

When I remove `multipart/form-data` from form, I am able to fetch the file but it gets corrupted.

Any lead on what is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: you should use `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file` to receive the file from jsp while receiving multipart form data.

Comment: Its resolved now.
Actually the bean that was to be created in the Config file was not getting invoked.

Answer (score 0):

try using a `@RequestParam` to extract the file from your request

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/bucket")
public ModelAndView exec(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

       InputStream fileStream = file.getInputStream(); //Return an InputStream to read the contents of the file from.

}
```